# Confirm line delete

Tags: vim, line, confirm

I have created a function to search all double lines in a file.

I use the "line-number"g/.*/d to delete the line.

However I would like to confirm if a line has to be deleted or not,
like the s/..//gc command

Is it possible to delete a certain line with the global or substitute
command and confirm every action?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954285/how-to-make-vims-global-command-confirm-able-before-executing-the-ex-command

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Why not try a substitute command instead of the delete command?

```
"line-number"s/^.*$\n//c
```

Comment: I had never thought of using `\n`, without which I had to use delete command...

Answer (score 7):

If I wanted to delete lines in a file and confirm each one, I would:

- search for the first one
- if I want to delete it, press `dd`
- search for the next one with `n`
- if I want to delete that, press `.`, else `n` again

Comment: it is not possible in my case. I do a check of every line with every other line and put the double line numbers in a list. Then I use the `\%l` code to put them all in a @/ variable and return it to the file. There in my opinion no way to "go to next" using a `\%l` in  the search.