# How to make vim's `:global` command confirm-able before executing the ex Command?

Tags: vim

How can I make vim's `:global` command ask the user if they want to execute the ex command? Similar to what happens with the `:substite` command with the 'c' option, for example `%s:Foo:Fighters:gc`

I tried:

```
:g/mypattern/.s:.*\n::gc
```

and

```
:g/mypattern/s:.*\n::gc
```

but if there is a match on below line it is jumped. For example:

```
MATCH
NONMATCH
MATCH

MATCH
MATCH
```

The result is:

```
NONMATCH

MATCH  <<-- this should be erased.
```

A promptable `g/FOO/d` would be perfect.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633496/confirm-line-delete

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no native way to do this. The typical method would be to record a macro and repeat a macro. Making sure you `n` or `/` at the end of the macro to advance to the next match. Skipping is now simply `n` and `@@` to execute the macro.

#### Custom `:Global` command

However if you truly want to have `:global` command with a confirm you can sort of mimic this by using `confirm()` inside the your command. The general idea is to do something like this:

```
:g/pat/if confirm("&yes\n&no", 2) == 1 | cmd | endif
```

This doesn't quite work for the following reasons:

- You have no idea where your cursor is. Need something like `:match` and `:redraw`
- Does not abort well. Need a way to throw an exception to abort
- Very unwieldily to type this all out

I have come up with the following confirming `:Global`/`:G` command

```
command! -nargs=+ -range=% -complete=command Global <line1>,<line2>call <SID>global_confirm(<q-args>)
command! -nargs=+ -range=% -complete=command G <line1>,<line2>call <SID>global_confirm(<q-args>)
function! s:global_confirm(args) range
  let args = a:args
  let sep = args[0]
  let [pat, cmd; _] = split(args[1:], '\v([^\\](\\\\)*\\)@<!%d' . char2nr(sep), 1) + ['', '']
  match none
  let options = ['throw "Global: Abort"', cmd, '', 'throw "Global: Abort"']
  let cmd = 'exe ''match IncSearch /\c\%''.line(''.'').''l''.@/.''/'''
  let cmd .= '| redraw'
  let cmd .= '| exe get(options, confirm("Execute?", "&yes\n&no\n&abort", 2))'
  try
    execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . 'g'.sep.pat.sep.cmd
  catch /Global: Abort/
  finally
    match none
  endtry
endfunction
```

Note: Use as-is. Uses `IncSearch` for highlight and forces `\c`.

Now you can run `:G/foo/d`.

#### Custom `:Confirm` command

If you rather use a similar technique to the one @Randy Morris provided and use the following `:Confirm {cmd}` command to confirm `{cmd}` before execution.

```
command! -nargs=+ -complete=command Confirm execute <SID>confirm(<q-args>) | match none
function! s:confirm(cmd)
  let abort = 'match none | throw "Confirm: Abort"'
  let options = [abort, a:cmd, '', abort]
  match none
  execute 'match IncSearch /\c\%' . line('.') . 'l' . @/ . '/'
  redraw
  return get(options, confirm('Execute?', "&yes\n&no\n&abort", 2), abort)
endfunction
```

This will allow you to use `:g/foo/Confirm d`

For more help see:

```
:h @
:h q
:h confirm()
:h :exe
:h get()
:h :match
:h :redraw
```

Comment: Really like this answer.  I would strongly recommend using `matchadd` and `matchdelete` rather than `:match` for highlighting the current line.  As it stands any manual matches or matches from other plugins will be cleared by this function.  `matchadd` and `matchdelete` allow you to specifically only clear your match when you are cleaning up.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no way to do this natively.  I think I've hacked together a way to do this but it's probably buggy as I haven't written vimscript in a long time.  In this I've defined a command `C` which accepts an ex command as its arguments.  Each line returned via `:global` is then passed to this ex command if you press <kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd>.  Any other key causes this line to be skipped.

```
let s:GlobalConfirmSignNumber = 42
sign define GlobalConfirmMarker text=>> texthl=Search

function GlobalConfirm(cmd)
    let line = getpos(".")[1]
    execute "sign place " . s:GlobalConfirmSignNumber . " line=" . line . " name=GlobalConfirmMarker file=" . expand("%:p")
    redraw!
    echomsg "Execute? (y/N) "
    try
        let char = nr2char(getchar())
        if (char == "y" || char == "Y")
             execute a:cmd
        endif
    finally
        " Ensure signs are cleaned up if execution is aborted.
        execute "sign unplace " . s:GlobalConfirmSignNumber
    endtry
    redraw!
endfunction

command -nargs=* C call GlobalConfirm(<q-args>)
```

Here's a gif of it in action.  In this gif I'm running the command `norm! gUU` for every line which contains `ba`.  In this case I confirmed every match by pressing <kbd>y</kbd> three times.

[image: gif in action]

If anyone can make improvements to this (especially the signs bit) please edit at will.

Comment: I use `:match IncSearch /pat/` to mark the matches. I like the use of `:C` instead of creating a new `:global` command like I initially did. I hope you don't mind but I used this idea as an another alternative in my post.

Comment: No, I don't mind at all.  I don't really like this answer as it stands, mainly because of the signs.  My only issue with your answer as it stands is that using `confirm` seems to screw up the display for me (and is why I didn't use it).  Since the confirm dialog takes up more than one line it pushes the text up and hides the first few lines in my test.  Not sure what's going on there.  This could be an artifact of the terminal I'm using, I'm not sure.

Comment: I really like how you used IncSearch to highlight the current line.  I would update my answer but I think we'd essentially be converging to the same thing so I'm going to leave mine as is just so there is some variety here.